# How do I get back to where I was... (roll back to previous commit) Git beginner

Tags: git

My last commands were:

```
git rebase -i HEAD^^

git rebase -i HEAD^^

git rebase -i HEAD^^^
```

How do I get the repository back to the state it was in before the first of the listed commands?

NOTE: all I have been doing thus far is `git commit -am "my commit message"`. I don't understand branching and merging yet so I haven't used them. I was trying to roll back the code to the previous commit, but this didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Just a cautionary note; git rebase can be incredibly destructive, especially if you're working from a shared repository. It's a good idea to learn how it works, but be careful using it in 'the real world' :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If those are the exact commands you've run, then `git reset --hard HEAD@{3}` will get you back to your HEAD as of 3 commands ago. More generally, look at the output of `git reflog` to come up with the ref you want to recover, and then `git reset` to that.

Comment: Not necessarily - HEAD can get updated a lot of times during an interactive rebase. `git reset --hard <branch>@{3}` would work, though - assuming all of the rebases actually did something. If they didn't, that'd be too far back in the history. I'd recommend looking at `git reflog show <branch>` to make sure you get what you want.

Comment: Will git checkout <file> accomplish the same thing, or will that have only worked prior to doing the rebases?

Comment: `git checkout <file>` grabs the version of `<file>` from the index and places it in the work tree. It only affects that file in the work tree. It has nothing to do with moving `HEAD` around.

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha. I had originally thought the OP wanted to do something different, but it makes much more sense now. Thanks!